# error in google sheets script: "TypeError: function split not found in object 0. (line16, file" SplitAuto ")."

Tags: google-sheets

I have a script that worked before, but for a few days, this one no longer works .....
I have an error:
`"TypeError: function split not found in object 0. (line16, file" SplitAuto ")."`
Can you help me please?

My script :

```
function splitAllTest(){
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var s=ss.getSheetByName("Réponses au formulaire 1");
var lr=s.getLastRow();
var lc=s.getLastColumn()-8; //data columns num
var range=s.getRange(1, 3, lr, lc).getValues()
var output=[];
var split=[]; 
var l = 0;      // outout row count 
for(var i=0;i<range.length;i++){  //row roop
  // split column_data
  var split = [];
  var max1  = 0; 
  for(var j=0;j<range[0].length;j++){  // column roop
    var colSplit = range[i][j].split(", ");
   split[j] = colSplit; 
   if(max1 < split[j].length) max1 = split[j].length;
  } 
  // push new rows data   
  for(var k=0;k<max1;k++){  // max1 
    output [l] = [];
    for(var j=0;j<lc;j++){  // column     
      if(k < split[j].length) {  // if length is 1  k is only 0
        output[l].push(split[j][k]);  // split [col_index][coldata_index]
      }else{
        //output[l].push('');          change 2017/03/08 takashi
        output[l].push(j == 0 ? split[j][0]: '');  //only first name is filled  on each associated line
    }}
    l++;
  }}
  ss.getSheetByName("Temp formulaire").clear().getRange(1, 2, 
  output.length,lc).setValues(output);
  }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you didn't use split as a variable. I kind of counted down what I think to be 16 and it's near this `range[i][j].split(", ")` probably something in that array is not a string. You might be able to coerce into a string like this `String(range[i][j]).split(', ');`

Comment: Hello, i find my error, i've add a column and i'vn't change number on line : <code>var lc=s.getLastColumn()-8; //data columns num</code>

Comment: sorry for the code